# run ionic Cordova command using exec, shell_exec, and backtick and return path empty

Tags: linux, laravel, cordova, ionic-framework

So, I'm trying to combine ionic and Laravel with the goal I am able to generate an APK based on what ionic **/www** folder show in my iframe tags, and my project structure is look like this:

```
- app
- artisan
- config
- database
- public
    - css
    - js
    - mobileapps
         - helloworld
              - www
                  - index.html (this is ionic generated /www folder that i show in my example site)
- resourece
- vendor
- etc...
```

I already use **exec()**, **shell_exec()** and **backticks** function to generate run **ionic Cordova build android**. I actually try to run this command manually in shell and it worked fine, but after I put in exec() command there's an error appear, I also change the project permission to **777** and make the owner as **www-data** still no luck.

This is my DemoController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DemoController extends Controller {

public function index() {
    return view('demo.index');
}

public function getAPK() {
    // download the apk
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 180);
    chdir('mobileapps/helloworld');
    exec('ionic cordova build android 2>&1', $output);

    return $output;

    // i wanted to return below code in order to make it downloadable if above **exec()** is working
    // return response()->download(public_path('mobileapps/helloworld/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk'));
    }
}
```

and this is my route web.php

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/demo', 'DemoController@index');
Route::post('/getapk', 'DemoController@getAPK');

?>
```

and the above $output is look like this:

```
> cordova platform add android --save path.js:39 throw new 
ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('path', 'string', path); ^ TypeError 
[ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string.
Received type undefined at assertPath (path.js:39:11) at Object.join 
(path.js:1152:7) at Object. 
(/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova- 
lib/src/cordova/util.js:36:31) at Module._compile 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30) at Object.Module._extensions..js 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10) at Module.load 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32) at tryModuleLoad 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12) at Function.Module._load 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3) at Module.require 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17) at require 
(internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18) [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova. cordova platform add android --save exited with exit code 1. Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

What I want is the **exec()**, **shell_exec()** and **backticks** to run **ionic Cordova build android** without above error so that I can get the APK file.

Sorry if my english is not good, I try my best to explain, hope you understand. Thank your for your help.